# when/where should properties be released once the objects is pushed for display?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've defined a view controller with an array as one of its properties, and set the array with an allocated and autoreleased array.
After I push the view for display I release it.

By watching the leaks tool I see that every time that I pop the view I suffer from leakage.
I tried to release the properties explicitly, immediately after the push but the app crashes.

looking forward for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leak is *probably* because of the array property is set to retain, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *yourArray;
```

Your autorelease object is retained on assignment to the yourArray property. Since it is retained, you have to release it in the controller's dealloc method:

```
- (void) dealloc {
   [yourArray release], yourArray = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

HTH.

Comment: WOW! So simple and I waisted hours on this.
Thanks. you made me happy :-)